# How to manage virtual keyboard (SIP) in Windows 10 to accommodate the view controls?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-10

Is there a tutorial or basic explanation where is documented how to manage the Soft Input Panel (SIP) in Windows 10 to accommodate the view controls?

Basically, now when the virtual keyboard appears in my Windows 10 Phone app, it hides the text boxes and the bottom tool bar. I need to re-accommodate the controls of the view, but I cannot info about events, patterns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Respond to the presence of the touch keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/mt185611.aspx)

For example:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        mInputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
        mInputPane.Showing += InputPane_Showing;
        mInputPane.Hiding += InputPane_Hiding; 
    }
```

..

```
    private void InputPane_Showing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
    {
        // Keyboard showing, get the size of the keyboard and adjust view.

        double keyboardHeight = args.OccludedRect.Height;

        aGridRow.Height = new GridLength(keyboardHeight);

        // Inform the system we have handled making the required UI visible.
        args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
    }
```

..

```
    private void InputPane_Hiding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
    {
        // Keyboard has disappeared, reset the view.

        aGridRow.Height = new GridLength(0);
        args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
    }
```